# Getting error while trying to upload a file in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to automate file uploading via cypress but getting the error below.
I am not finding the root cause of the issue.

```
enter code here
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

Script error.

Cypress detected that an uncaught error was thrown from a cross origin script.

We cannot provide you the stack trace, line number, or file where this error occurred.

Check your Developer Tools Console for the actual error - it should be printed there.

It's possible to enable debugging these scripts by adding the crossorigin attribute and 
setting a CORS header.

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically 
fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the 
uncaught:exception event
```

Below is my code

```
it('Single File Upload-DOM', () => {
    cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/Help%20Folder/fileupload.html')
    cy.get('#file-upload1').attachFile('dog_small.jpg')
    cy.get('span#fileName1').should('have.text','dog_small.jpg')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off the exception check globally by writing:

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

under `cypress/support/index.js`

Comment: Great but why these kind of issues come.
I just wanted to know the root cause.

Comment: This exception is generated on the application end(and not cypress) as mentioned in the error message. So you have to debug the application to find out more. You can start from here `Check your Developer Tools Console for the actual error - it should be printed there.`